# Automatic tables rendering in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, user-interface, jsp-tags

Is there any way to automate process of rendering tables with Spring MVC? I'm looking for some mechanism for automated rendering List of POJO's on JSP instead of manual writing code like this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty objects}">
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="o" items="${objects}">
            <tr>
                <td>${o.id}</td>
                <td>${o.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Probably something like this:

```
<awesometaglib:smarttable data="${listOfPOJOs}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_basic.html) or any other library.

Comment: Seems nice. And is there any built-in-spring technologies (without using external libraries)?

Comment: OK, looks like it's the only way. Thanks.